# Count all <a> on html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get all the `<a>` tags from an `Html` page with this `JavaScript` method:

```
function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i=0;
    for (var link in links){i++;}
    return i;
}
```

And i noticed it's won't return the correct number of a tags.

Any idea what can by the problem?

Any idea if there is any other way to get all the href in an `Html` ?

## Edit

I tried this method on this html : http://mp3skull.com/mp3/nirvana.html . 
And i get this result:"1". but there are more results in the page.

Comment: How many tags expected? How many tags actually found?

Comment: Why not var linksCount = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; ?

Comment: I expect to get 30+ link and i get only 3

Comment: SHow us a working, mimla example then, please. The code is OK now.

Comment: @MTA you should not edit your question with the answer. Rather, accept an answer!

Comment: @StarsSky It's not the answer to the question.

Comment: @MTA Even using the length property?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need a loop here. You can read `length` property.

```
function getACount() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the one-liner but this will only return the number of links. I'm not sure he just wanted an overall count.

Comment: @Drewness well the original solution will (well... would) only return the total count, too...

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to loop over all of them just to count them. [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)s (the type of Object that is returned by `getElementsByTagName` has a `.length` property:

```
$countAnchors = function () {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `getElementsByTagName("a")` will return all anchor tags, not only the anchor tags that are links. An anchor tags needs a value for the `href` property to be a link.

You might be better off with the [`links` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.links), that returns the links in the page:

```
var linkCount = document.links.length;
```

Note that this also includes `area` tags that has a `href` attribute, but I assume that you don't have any of those.

Comment: I tried this method on this html : http://mp3skull.com/mp3/nirvana.html . And i get only 1 results. but i have more results in the page.

Comment: @MTA: It gives the expected result, because there is actually only one real link in the page. If you want anchor elements that are not links, then the `links` property is not what you should use.

Comment: @MTA i don't know how do you reveice only 1 result. After testing it with the chrome console, i get `334 Results`

Comment: @demonking: Then it would be because links are added to the page after it is loaded. The source of the page only contains a single link.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Also gets href

**You could do this**

```
var linkCount = document.body.querySelectorAll('a').length,
    hrefs= document.body.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
```

**EDIT** See the comment below, thanks to ttepasse

Comment: `var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("a[href]");`

Answer (score 0):

I would cast them to an array which you then slice up, etc.

```
var array = [];
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    array.push(links[i].href);
}
var hrefs = array.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code in the question works as such or, rather, could be used to create a working solution (it’s now just an anonymous function declaration). It could be replaced by simpler code that just uses `document.getElementsByTagName('a').length` as others have remarked.

The problem however is how you use it: where it is placed, and when it is executed. If you run the code at a point where only one `a` element has been parsed, the result is 1. It needs to be executed when all `a` elements have been parsed. A simple way to ensure this is to put the code at the end of the document body. I tested by taking a local copy of the page mentioned and added the following right before the other `script` elements at the end of document body:

```
<script>
var f = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i=0;
    for (var link in links){i++;}
    return i;
};
alert('a elements: ' + f());
</script>
```

The results are not consistent, even on repeated load of the page on the same browser, but this is probably caused by some dynamics on the page, making the number of `a` elements actually vary.

Answer (score -1):

What you forget here was the `length` property. I think that code would be:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  count++;
}
return count;
```

Or it would be:

```
for each (var link in links) {
  i++;
}
```

`length` is used to determine or count the total number of the element which are the result.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for (For Loop)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in (Foreach Loop)

Comment: Eeeeh... Why in your first example you're using a variable `count` and increment it `links.length` times? Why don't returns `links.length` directly, do like make your CPU works for nothing? :D

Comment: Speaking of looping: for-each is deprecated, a hack (because of its E4X-inheritance and will be replaced in the far future with for-of.Worse: it loops over the properties of an object not over the array-like indices.

Better ways of looping are:
• `[1, 2, 3].forEach(function (el, index), { ... })` for Arrays
• `Object.keys().forEach(function (key) {... })` for the properties of an object. 
• `Array.prototype.forEach(document.links, function () { ...});` for Array-like objects like the HTMLCollection `document.links` returns.